# ImportError: No module named shutil_get_terminal_size

Tags: python, scipy, ipython

I have started to install SciPy using:

```
pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas simply nose
```

It installed but when I want to go into ipython I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named shutil_get_terminal_size
```

I tried uninstalling python then reinstalling it as well as uninstalling and reinstalling SciPy. I've also upgraded pip setup tools as well as python. It says that shutil_get_terminal_size has been installed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 7, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 28, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 128, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.terminal import get_terminal_size
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/terminal.py", line 22, in <module>
    from backports.shutil_get_terminal_size import get_terminal_size as _get_terminal_size
ImportError: No module named shutil_get_terminal_size
```

I just need to be able to get SciPy and ipython working.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your version of pip and then install ipython again.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
pip uninstall --user ipython
pip install --user ipython
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue.This is the issue of conda environment. That's why it is giving the error in ipython notebook.Try out this one.

```
conda update conda

conda update ipython
```

After trying this,if you are facing same issue.then try to install ipython inside your conda environment.Activate your conda environment first.then do as follows.

```
     pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
  ex:  (dato-env) pydev@Optimus:~$ pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
```

then install ipython inside conda environment

```
    pip install -U ipython
    ex : (dato-env) pydev@Optimus:~$ pip install -U ipython
```

then open Jupyter notebook from the terminal and it will open jupyter on your browser.

```
(dato-env) pydev@Optimus:~$ jupyter notebook
```

Hope it helps.